# Participles Functioning as Adverbials

Tags: participle-clauses, adverbials

I've read that 'participles functioning as adverbials' can be usefully viewed as reduced forms of adverb clauses. My question is *can all participles functioning as adverbials be reconstituted into full adverb clauses?*

Example sentence: "He stood bowed and shrunken, weighed down by his great-coat, a white muffler fluttering untidily at his throat, a cloth cap pulled down on his forehead, his face white and lined, his nose colored by the cold . . ."

After "great-coat" we have four participles functioning as adverbials, no? But I don't think they could be reconstituted into full adverb clauses.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "full adverb clauses". They are supplementary adjuncts (your 'adverbials'), loosely attached expressions set off by intonation and punctuation, presenting supplementary non-integrated content. More specifically, they are 'absolute' constructions because they are non-finite, they have a subject, and they have no syntactic link to the main clause.

Comment: My textbook says that "Working diligently on his paper,..." is a reduced adverb clause which could be reconstituted as "While he was working diligently on his paper,..." The reduced adverb clause could be changed back into a full adverb clause. However, this book also says that the second part of this sentence "She walked along hurriedly, HER PURSE CLUTCHED TIGHTLY IN HER ARMS" is another example. And, I suppose, that could be reconstituted as "while her purse was clutched tightly in her arms"??

Comment: Yes: the non-finite clause "working diligently on his paper" could be expanded to "while he was working diligently on his paper". which (in modern grammar) is a preposition phrase, not a clause.  The same applies to your other example. The important contrast is that between a non-finite clause and some other expression, which may or may not be a clause.

Comment: Are you mistakenly thinking that 'muffler' is describing the aforementioned coat? A muffler is a scarf. So what you have is an adjective (white), a noun (muffler), a verb (fluttering) and an adverb (untidily).

Comment: Oh, no, wasn't thinking that. I think I've actually found my answer in something called 'absolute constructions'.